# Get cell value from a spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, spreadsheet, openxml-sdk

I have a spreadsheet with 10 columns, I want for example to inform the cell value and the column and get back the value contained in the cell that is in the same row found but in a different column.

In the picture for example I want to give the cell value "b" and the column A then search the line where "b" was found and get back the value from the same line but in a different column, in the example Column H, value "PPP".

Comment: Consider using `VLOOKUP()`

Comment: What does this have to do with OpenXML?

Comment: I need to have the value in a C# application, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, put this at the top of the file with the rest of the "using" directives (you will need to set a reference to Excel Interop Assembly):

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then do the following to open your worksheet so you can access it in C#:

```
string ExcelFilePath = "somepath";
string WorksheetName = "sheet1";//or whatever the name of your worksheet is
var excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
excel.Visible = true;

Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[WorksheetName];
```

Then do something like this to get the value of a cell. Keep in mind that Excel rows and columns are 1 based, not 0 based, so the topmost leftmost cell is [1,1].

```
Excel.Range myCell = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
string myValue = myCell.Value2;
```

Notice that there is "excel" (lower case e) and "Excel" (upper case E). The "excel" variable is an instance of the Excel application. "Excel" is a namespace to access types within the Excel namespace (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel) like "Workbook" and "Range".

Comment: You could also get an entire row like "Excel.Range myRow = worksheet.Rows[3]; And then get a cell value like "myRow[2].Value2" so that you could loop through the columns in the row to look for the value you are trying to match.